# Peltier Thermoelectric Module - Water Cooling

Tags: thermodynamics, water, thermal-conduction

My questions concerns calculations about a Peltier Thermoelectric Module for the cooling of water between an inlet and outlet. The Peltier water cooling module I am referring to is the following: [Peltier Water Cooling Module](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/385113292239?chn=ps&_ul=GB&_trkparms=ispr%3D1&amdata=enc%3A1ryn43pP1SzGha5zHAm1PRw7&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=710-169684-232771-8&mkcid=2&itemid=385113292239&targetid=293946777986&device=c&mktype=pla&googleloc=9187053&poi=&campaignid=20646531776&mkgroupid=160183588928&rlsatarget=pla-293946777986&abcId=&merchantid=646523451&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAjw48-vBhBbEiwAzqrZVBI9I7j-7nMEENjip16yIya9DwbMGE0mpqxRzJcR9s2yqmMo8Cii4BoCv8EQAvD_BwE), and looks like this (the small fan is used to cool the heat sink):

[image]

Let's say I have information about:

- Efficiency of the Peltier itself: 5%
- Consumption Power: 70 W
- The maximum temperature difference between the hot and cold side of the Peltier, independent of the temperature of hot side: approx. 60°C
- Assume a temperature of the cold side of about -10°C e.g.
- The inlet water temperature is 30°C

The water flows through the blue element and encounters small seperation walls such as in a heat exchanger. Assuming a 1 l/min flow rate, how can I reasonably (but by making assumptions) compute what the temperature difference will be between the inlet and outlet?

What reasoning can I use to calculate the heat transfer between the peltier module and the blue element, and what the corresponding temperature of my water will be at the outlet?

I would be very happy for your help and tips.

Kind regards,

FBMeca

N.B. The datasheet of the Peltier element used in this cooling module, the TEC1-12706, gives following information:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First the bad news; the best you can expect at 1l/min is a temperature change of about ¾ C.

If you look at the complete specs for this device you will find that Q=60watts (max) occurs when the delta T across it is 0C. For a reasonable delta T of 40C you can expect only about 40w of cooling, this with high side T of 50C as you need to dump that heat into ambient with a small fan. [Peltier data sheet](https://peltiermodules.com/peltier.datasheet/TEC1-12706.pdf)
[image: Peltier Data]

If you have an electric kettle of 1kW, that takes about 4 seconds to heat one liter of water by 1 C. To cool water by removing 1kW of heat, the time per degree is the same. (Heat capacity of water =4.16kJ/(kg*C)

So if you have 40w of cooling it will take 100 seconds to cool one liter of water by one degree Centigrade. This is assuming perfect and instantaneous heat flow through the heat exchanger from the Peltier device to the water, which I think you can do as it looks like it’s aluminum which is an excellent conductor, and the conduction rate to water is also excellent.  To cool 1l of water from 30C to 1C would take 48 minutes.

I think your estimate of 30C for incoming water is high, unless you have it sitting outside on a sunny day. Probably 20C is a better figure, in which case it would take only 32 minutes. Well actually it would take longer for both of these as the heat transfer capability of this unit falls to about 22w at 50C delta T. (Just take the average rate of heat transfer from lowest delta T to highest as the graph is linear)

As a final note, you would never want the temperature of the low side to be -10C if you’re cooling water. If for any reason the flow of water was interrupted your device would freeze solid. (It would probably freeze up anyway as ice built up on the walls and slowed the flow)

EDIT: Some basic heat transfer calculations

1. Cooling water
   Temperature change $\Delta T = Q*t/(M*c)$

c = 4184 J/(kg*K)   Specific heat capacity of water.

(If you want to reduce the temperature of 1l (1kg) of water by $10^oC$ you need to remove 41840 Joules)

Q  = Cooling Capacity of Peltier device in watts
M = mass of water in kg
T =  temperature in $^oC$
t = time in seconds

Example cooling 1kg water with 40w of cooling for 5 min $\Delta T = (40*5*60)/(4184*1) =2.84^oC$

2. Heat transfer across an aluminum block
   Heat flow across an aluminum block $Q=kA\Delta T/d$
   A = Area of block in $m^2$
   k = Thermal conductivity of aluminum 237w/(m*K)
   d = thickness in m
   Q = heat flow in watts (J/s)
   Example   Heat flow across $16cm^2$ block 0.5cm thick    with $1^oC$ $\Delta T$
   $Q =237*0.0016*1/0.005=75.8w$
   (It takes about $.5^o$ C temp difference to drive 40 watt of cooling across a 4cm square block 0.5cm thick - So basically you can ignore this, especially if you are going to precool the block.)
3. How much heat must be removed to cool an aluminum block?
   Q = $cm\Delta T$
   c = specific heat capacity of aluminum (0.9 J/(g*K)
   m = mass of aluminum in grams
   Example cooling a 100g block of aluminum $20^o C$    $Q= 0.9 *100*20=1800J$ to be removed

Comment: Hi Rich,
Thank you for your answer. There are a few things I don't understand, and I maybe made myself not very clear:
- First of all, I don't quite understand these graphs. Is delta_T the temperature difference between the hot and cold sides of the Peltier? If so, how come we have maximum cooling power Q_c when delta_T is zero? Intuitively I would have said the larger the temperature difference, the larger the cooling power (e.g. hot side at 50 degrees, cold side at 0 degrees) ? 
- I understand your reasoning for the water kettle. Only difference here is we are cooling the flowing water...

Comment: and not a volume of water. So in my case, I mean that the flow rate through the blue element is 1l/min, from which I want to assume what the water temperature at the outlet of the blue element will be. Maybe take a look at this video https://youtu.be/pvtm7dFGl_4?t=383, where he is doing exactly what I mean. He cools it down by approximately 11 degrees Celsius with a certain flowrate and certain peltier elements.

So would you or anyone know of a way to compute the outlet temperature reasonably by doing some physics/heat transfer calculations?

Thanks a lot!

Johmi

Comment: As I said in my answer, if you run water through at 1l/min it will cool down by 0.75C.   In the video he has 300W of Peltier cooling, that’s four times yours. He precools the aluminum block for about 5 min, which acts as a heat sink, and cools about 1l coke.
So we have .75*4*5= 15C temperature change, but he actually got about 13C change. That’s because my estimate of 0.75C was a little high.     I'll add some equations to my answer when I have a little more time.      (The cooling effect is higher at small delta T across the Peltier because the work required to move heat is less.)

Comment: I did not understand your 0.75C correctly. So these 0.75C is without any precooling (or let's say from the moment we turn the Peltier on), and it gets increased by 0.75 * times of precooling minutes (to a certain point it becomes constant)? I would be interested in how you computed the 0.75C, this is something you computed yourself, or found somewhere?

Equations would also very much help, looking forward to that. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi Rich. I saw the edit you made and the calculations you added, thanks a lot. But I don't completely grasp your reasoning. I am not heating a volume of water in a tank with a peltier element, instead the water flows through the blue element (cooled by the Peltier) and is cooled like that. Hence it's a dynamic problem, not a static one.
Could you explain me how your reasoning is valid still for this problem? Shouldn't one be analyzing the blue heat exchanger element in more detail to understand how the Peltier and the blue element cool the water?
Thanks for your clarifications in advance!

Comment: #2 shows the heat flow across the blue element (aluminum) from the water to the Peltier module. I included this just to show that basically you can ignore it - it's a small temperature drop across the block.

Comment: #3 is a calculation for if you want to precool the block.

Comment: #1 can be used for static or for flowing conditions. If for flow, then the water has to pass through very slowly to get any appreciable cooling. With a 40W element cooling is going to be very slow. If you pass 1l through at 200cc/min you will get about 3C cooling. I think if you want to cool water on the go, you'll need one heck of a lot of Peltier modules! Even cooled drinking water fountains have a cooled reservoir, they are not instant. Here's a link to help with your design. https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/choosing-using-advanced-peltier-modules-thermoelectric-cooling

Comment: Perfect, I understand all your calculations. Actually #1 is simply $\dot{Q} = \dot{m} \cdot C_p \Delta T$ but then rewritten, so it makes sense. But in the video I showed you, he still manages to cool down the water by 13 degrees celsius with a cooling power of 300 W and a flow rate of more than 1 liter/minute, which for me is not a low flow rate.

Comment: If you compute it you obtain $\dot{Q} = 875 \ W$ which is still pretty large, and he manages to do so with a Peltier of 300 W. Then as you said the precooling makes the difference to increase these 300 W right? As the aluminium blue element stores cold energy during precooling..

Comment: And when you say "cool it on the go", do you mean without precooling? Because with precooling it seems doable to cool it down, but without precooling I am not sure it could work out. E.g. Cool it down by 15 degrees celsius, with 1 liter/min flow rate, What do you think?

Comment: If you want to cool 1l of water by 15C you need to remove 4184x15 = 62760J of heat.  Without precooling, to do this in one minute you need 1050w of cooling. If you precool your unit for 5 min you need about 200w cooling.  It would be good for you to try out the calculations yourself. In all cases you do need to check other peoples calculations. This has always been my experience - especially with a company that gives you a quote for some mechanical service they offer. You'd be surprised how often they only give the most rosy estimates!

Comment: Thanks a lot Rich for your help. I am going to pursue all of this on my end now :)

Comment: Which Peltier unit are you planning to use? Don't forget to use thermal grease between components to improve heat flow. Add a comment on how it goes.

Comment: I will post a comment once I get forward. Such a system is probably not gonna work with the outlet temperature and flow rate that I set, so what will be needed is a way to store cold energy, such as a block of aluminium. A coil would then be casted in this block which allows for the transfer of heat between the water and cold aluminium block. We will see how it goes...